# JAXB/MOXy wrong unmarshalling result

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I'm using JAXB/MOXy to unmarshall an XML file containing around 50 Objects of this class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Message")
public class MyClass{

private String name="";


private String messageComment;


private String messageType;


private Vector<Param> params = new Vector<Param>();

private String subtype;

public UcipMessageUnmarshaller(){}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@XmlElement
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Vector<Param> getParams() {
    return params;
}

@XmlElementWrapper(name="params")
@XmlElement (name="param")
public void setParams(Vector<Param> params) {
    this.params = params;
}

public static Param getParam(String name, Boolean mandatory){
    return new Param(name, mandatory);
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.messageComment = comment;
}


@XmlAttribute(name="comment")
public void setMessageComment(String messageComment) {
    this.messageComment = messageComment;
}

@XmlAttribute(name="type")
public void setMessageType(String messageType) {
    this.messageType = messageType;
}


@XmlAttribute(name="comment")
public String getMessageComment() {
    return messageComment;
}

public String getMessageType() {
    return messageType;
}

public String getSubtype() {
    return subtype;
}

@XmlElement
public void setSubtype(String subtype) {
    this.subtype = subtype;
}
    }
```

but I'm encountering a weird problem : some of my Objects are having a very strange "name", for example one of them is getting : `y></pstRefillAccountAfterFlag` others are having a part of their name mixed with a part of the name of another object.

here is an example of my XML file :

```xml
<Message>
    <name>MessageName</name>
    <params>
        <param>
            <name>Param1Name</name>
            <mandatory>true</mandatory>
        </param>
        <param>
            <name>Param2Name</name>
            <mandatory>true</mandatory>
        </param>
        <param>
            <name>Param3Name</name>
            <mandatory>true</mandatory>
        </param>
        <param>
            <name>Param4Name</name>
            <mandatory>true</mandatory>
        </param>
        <param>
            <name>Param4Name</name>
            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
        </param>
        <param>
            <name>Param5Name</name>
            <mandatory>true</mandatory>
        </param>
        <param>
            <name>Param6Name</name>
            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
        </param>
    </params>
</Message>
```

it's the `<name>` value that's coming erroneous.

what could possibly be the reason ?

PS: the result will differ (but always wrong) if I change my file between linearized and pretty-printed XML.

BR

Comment: Could you provide some additional information:  Which version of EclipseLink are you using?  What input type are you unmarshalling from?  Are you aware if there are any non-default SAX or StAX parsers on the classpath?

Comment: Hi Blaise, I'm using EclipseLink 2.4.1
not sure what you mean the input type, I'll edit the original question and add an xml example.
apart from eclipselink, nothing related to XML is in my classpath.

Comment: Does your example XML return the wrong name?  If so, what name does it return?

Comment: @Rima - Unmarshalling from `InputStream`, `File`, etc

Comment: I've one parameter named "RefillAccountAfterFlag" and I'm getting "y></pstRefillAccountAfterFlag" there is one other parameter that's coming as a mix between itself and another parameter's name

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I'm unmarshalling from a file using this code :
    `File methods1 = new File("messages001.xml");
    context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
    m = context.createUnmarshaller();
    a = (MyClass) m.unmarshal(methods1);`

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan here is a link of an eclipse project that reproduces the error, setup a break point at line 72 in AIRIP.java, run the debug, and have a look at `a -> messages -> elementData[26] -> params -> elementData[15] -> name` for an example of this error.

edit: you'll have to add the eclipselink jar to your porject
[link](https://rapidshare.com/files/4092394426/reproduceXMLError.zip)

Comment: I've added an answer (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13460346/383861).  The problem appears to be that the underlying parser is return invalid character events to MOXy when the XML header contains `version="1.1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

> @BlaiseDoughan here is a link of an eclipse project that reproduces
>   the error, setup a break point at line 72 in AIRIP.java, run the
>   debug, and have a look at a -> messages -> elementData[26] -> params
>   -> elementData[15] -> name for an example of this error. edit: you'll have to add the eclipselink jar to your porject [link](https://rapidshare.com/files/4092394426/reproduceXMLError.zip)

Based on the project you linked to (thank you for providing that).  If you remove MOXy from the picture you see interesting results:

**SAXDemo**

Currently when you unmarshal from a `File` MOXy will process the XML input using a SAX parser.  Below I've created a simple application that uses a SAX parser to process the XML document you provided and output the contents of all the character events that contain the String "<".

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SAXDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        xr.setContentHandler(new DefaultHandler() {

            @Override
            public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                    throws SAXException {
                String string = new String(ch, start, length);
                if(string.contains("<")) {
                    System.out.println(string);
                }
            }}
       );

       xr.parse("ressources/messages001.xml");
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  Most of the lines correspond to content id `CDATA` sections so they're expected, but the line `/param><param><name>subscrlag` is not.  This means that reason MOXy is unmarshalling the wrong value is that the underlying SAX parser is reporting the wrong characters event.

```
<node relation=\"XOR\"><name>adjustmentAmountRelative</name><name>mainAccountValueNew</name></node><node relation=\"AND\" comment=\"in case the request is an update of already assigned community\"><name>communityInformationCurrent</name><name>communityInformationNew</name></node>
<node relation=\"AND\"><name>promotionPlanID</name><name>promotionStartDate</name><name>promotionEndDate</name></node>
/param><param><name>subscrlag
<node relation=\"XOR\"><name>adjustmentAmountRelative</name><name>mainAccountValueNew</name></node><node relation=\"XOR\"><name>supervisionExpiryDateRelative</name><name>supervisionExpiryDate</name></node><node relation=\"XOR\"><name>serviceFeeExpiryDateRelative</name><name>serviceFeeExpiryDate</name></node>
<node relation=\"OR\"><name>msisdnCurrent</name><name>msisdnCurrentNAI</name><name>msisdnNew</name><name>msisdnNewNAI</name><name>imsiCurrent</name><name>imsiNew</name><name>naiCurrent</name><name>naiNew</name><name>sipUriCurrent</name><name>sipUriNew</name><name>privateCurrent</name><name>privateNew</name></node><node relation=\"XOR\"><name>chargingInformation</name><name>externalContract</name></node>
<node relation=\"AND\" comment=\"in case the request is an update of already assigned community\"><name>communityInformationCurrent</name><name>communityInformationNew</name></node>
<node relation=\"XOR\"><name>fafInformation</name><name>fafInformationList</name></node><node relation=\"AND\"><name>selectedOption</name><name>chargingRequestInformation</name></node>
<node relation=\"XOR\"><node relation=\"\"><name>updateAction</name><name>productID</name></node><node relation=\"\"><node relation=\"XOR\"><node relation=\"OR\"><node relation=\"XOR\"><name>startDate</name><name>startDateRelative</name><node relation=\"\" comment=\"Optional\"><name>startPamPeriodIndicator</name><name>currentTimeOffset</name></node></node><node relation=\"XOR\"><name>expiryDate</name><name>expiryDateRelative</name><name>expiryPamPeriodIndicator</name></node></node><node relation=\"OR\"><node relation=\"XOR\"><name>startDateTime</name><name>startDateTimeRelative</name></node><node relation=\"XOR\"><name>expiryDateTime</name><name>expiryDateTimeRelative</name></node></node></node><name>pamServiceID</name><name>offerType</name><name>offerProviderID</name><name>dedicatedAccountUpdateInformation</name><name>attributeUpdateInformationList</name></node></node>
<node relation=\"OR\"><name>promotionRefillAmountRelative</name><name>promotionRefillCounterStepRelative</name><name>progressionRefillAmountRelative</name><name>progressionRefillCounterStepRelative</name></node>
<node relation=\"OR\"><name>accountGroupID</name><name>serviceOfferings</name></node>
<node relation=\"OR\"><name>usageCounterUpdateInformation</name><name>usageThresholdUpdateInformation</name></node>
```

**ISSUE - XML Version 1.1**

Your XML document contains the following header with the version set to `1.1`.  If you change the version to be `1.0` everything seems to work properly.  The default SAX parser implementation in the JDK appears to fail when the version is set to `1.1`.

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

**SOLUTION - Use Another SAX Parser**

The good thing about using a standard parser API such as SAX is that you can always swap in a new parser.  I ran your example adding Xerces2 Java Parser 2.11.0 Release to the classpath, and the example ran as expected.

- http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/

Comment: thanks a lot Blaise, indeed the problem is fixed by using xerces :)